# How to truncate numbers?

Tags: python

I have digits, for example:

```
100.1264
9.09
123
1298.456789
```

and I want to truncate this to:

```
100.12
9.09
123
1298.45
```

How to truncate those numbers so as to leave their form?

Comment: What do you mean *"digits"*? Are they part of a string, or number objects? Do you want them *displayed* rounded to 2dp, or actually rounded? And what have *you* tried so far? Please provide more information.

Comment: nips did you try anything? show us what you tried as a python code.

Comment: please refer this answer this might help you.
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
s="""100.1264
9.09
123
343.1
1298.456789"""
print re.sub(r"(?<=\.)(\d{2})\d+",r"\1",s)
```

If your input is a float you can use

```
s=100.1264

print ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r"(?<=\.)(\d{2})\d+",r"\1",str(s)))
```

Comment: Casting to a string, regular expression-ing it and converting back (with `literal_eval`, not `float`?!) seems inefficient compared to e.g. `int(s * 100) / 100.0`...

Comment: @jonrsharpe round(4.1234) gives `4.0` ?

Comment: Yes, I realised that shortly after commenting. As pointed out elsewhere `math.trunc` is also available though, and the point is that the round trip through string seems like an odd way to approach it.

Comment: @jonrsharpe i have no idea `math.trunk`

Answer (score 1):

If you have numbers (not strings), you can use:

```
import math
math.trunc(x * 100) / 100
```

For example:

```
>>> import math
>>> x = 100.1264
>>> math.trunc(x * 100) / 100
100.12
```

<sub>You may also use `int` in place of `math.trunc`, however beware that casts between floats and ints may be computationally expensive.</sub>

**Bonus tip:** if you want arbitrary precision decimal arithmetic, take a look at the [`decimal` module](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/decimal.html).